# Dividing values in one DF with multi-indexing by values from another and plotting results

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DF, that contains N students and grades in different subject:

```
ANA  Math      96.0
     Biology   82.0
     Chemistry 72.0
TONY Math      77.0
     Biology   100.0
     Chemistry 82.0
ARI  Math      94.0
     Biology   98.0
```

I wish to plot a bar graph with the grades for **all** subject for 3 **best** students (in descending order),when best student is the one who have the highest avg grade for **all** the subject he had.

In the plot ,**for each student**, **each grade** should be multiplied by its  values in df2 (each student have different value):

```
ANA  0.80
TONY 0.75
ARI  0.95
```

for ex: ANA grades in the plot should be:

```
ANA  Math      76.8
     Biology   65.6
     Chemistry 57.6
```

I've managed to plot the graph for the best 3 students, however the students are not ordered in descending order.
Moreover, I have not find a way to multiplied the grades by the values in df2  for each student before plotting it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
top3 = df.groupby(level=0).mean().nlargest(3).index.tolist()
df.sort_index().loc[top3].mul(df2, level=0)

0     1        
ANA   Biology      65.60
      Chemistry    57.60
      Math         76.80
ARI   Biology      93.10
      Math         89.30
TONY  Biology      75.00
      Chemistry    61.50
      Math         57.75
dtype: float64
```